# Syntax error trying to run batch files in loop

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, infinite-loop

I want to run these 3 .bat files in loop. Tried these 2 codes and got invalid syntax error from both

```
@echo off
:loop
start "c:\1.bat" && "c:\2.bat" && "c:\3.bat" &&
GOTO :loop
```

and

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 9999) do (
    start "c:\1.bat" && "c:\2.bat" && "c:\3.bat" &&
   set /a loopCount=%loopCount%-1
   if %loopCount%==0 GOTO:EOF
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe too many `&&` and should use a space before `:EOF`.

Personally, I'd avoid using `&&` for future maintenance and readability.

If you want 1.bat, 2.bat, and 3.bat to remain on-screen, use `/K` shown below.  Otherwise, use `/C` so 1.bat, 2.bat, and 3.bat can exit after running.

I'm not sure the purpose of `%loopCount%` -- other than a loop exit safeguard -- but be sure to initialize that variable ahead of using it (good coding practice).

Here's an example:

```
@echo off
set /a maxLoop=5
set /a loopCount=%maxLoop%
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %maxLoop%) do (
   start %COMSPEC% /K c:\1.bat
   start %COMSPEC% /K c:\2.bat
   start %COMSPEC% /K c:\3.bat
   set /a loopCount=%loopCount%-1
   if "%loopCount%"=="0" GOTO :EOF
)
```

Comment: With that example would 1,2,3 run at the same time? I want them to run in sequence should I add && there ?

Comment: In that case, I might replace `start %COMSPEC% /K` above with simply `CALL`; rather than rely on multiple `&&` after start.

Comment: if i use CALL will they run in sequent?

Comment: Give it a try.  You can always go back to using `&&` if it doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: Ok now it works as intended. Thank you